# Full name of user does not always show up when using @-mention in comment

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

Normally, we use '@' before the name of the previous commenter to notify a user, and when we type two or three letters of the name, Stack Overflow, suggests the full name and we can click on it.

But sometimes I can't @-mention the commenter. I mean I write the full name, but Stack Overflow doesn't suggest them. Why? Is that OK and will they be notified? Or is that suggestion by Stack Overflow required to notify them?

Comment: FYI see also detailed answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are cases when the @ mention is unnecessary and blocked:

1. If the person you are mentioning is the owner of the question/answer you are commenting on then you don't need their user name for them to see the comment.

   You always get notification of any comment on your own posts.
2. If only one other person has left comments on a post, then that person is automatically notified of your reply. In that case the system assumes that you are replying to that person.

Comment: How can you mark people with empty strings in their names?

Comment: Hi @ChrisF, there is no autocomplete, so not sure you will get this?