# How to reply to a comment?

Tags: support, comments

Many times I see in the comments that one comment replies to an other with author's name  like @name. I've tried to do this currently with no success. When I literally try to start my comment with @name sometimes it strips the @, sometime it strips the complete name. Besides of this it is very inconvenient to copy and paste the name.

I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: For starters it should autocomplete, and it isn't required if you are responding to the OP so it gets stripped in that case

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260759/full-name-of-user-does-not-always-show-up-when-using-mention-in-comment) similar to what you experience?

Comment: @rene trying autocomplete

Comment: And how did that work out?

Comment: @rene I think I got it. Thx

Comment: sometimes this happened to me also

Answer (score 5):

Short version: author of the post will always be notified and you can't use "@authror_name" (will be auto-removed). Otherwise in most cases you'll get auto-complete options when you type '@'.

Full version on big meta as linked by Servy: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @Alexi_Levnekow ...like this?