# Why are @name mention syntaxes in comments only allowed at the front?

Tags: support, comment-replies

See the second and third comment posted at [Finding a type-safe replacement for int argument to a C++ function representing one or more operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307544/finding-a-type-safe-replacement-for-int-argument-to-a-c-function-representing#comment91578132_52307544) where I had wanted to add a single paragraph and mention both people in the same comment, but no, when I typed the second "@" followed by a "j", then the second person's name did not popup in a tiny popup window. So I had to do something cumbersome and use ellipses in both comments to complete the sentence.

That is cumbersome.

Is that by design?

Note that this is *not* a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260761/257924 as I'm specifically talking about the *second* commenter.

Comment: *specifically talking about the second commenter*: You can't use more than one `@name` in a comment. You can't add a second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't mention more than one user in a single comment. That's why it didn't work.

You can mention people anywhere in your comment.

For more info, see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/369403)